# Changing the case of the first letter of the word in a file using C

Tags: c, file-handling

I am trying to change  the case of first letter of the word from a file using C.

For example, if the file contains sentence: `good morning.how are you?`
Then it will be changed to `Good Morning.How Are You?`

I tried a lot but cannot produce the desired result.
Can anyone help me?  I use this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {
    FILE *fp1;
    char ch;
    int p;

    fp1 = fopen("asiftext.txt", "a+");
    ch = fgetc(fp1);
    if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') {
        fseek(fp1, -1, 1);
        ch = toupper(ch);
        fputc(ch, fp1);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
        if (ch == ' ' || ch == '\n') {
            ch = fgetc(fp1);
            if (ch == EOF)
                break;
            if (ch >= 97 && ch <= 122) {
                fseek(fp1, -1, 1);
                fputc(ch - 32, fp1);
            }
        }
    }
    /*ch = fgetc(fp1);
    p = ftell(fp1);
    printf("p1=%d", p);
    printf("%c\n", ch);
    fseek(fp1, -1, 1);
    fputc(ch - 32,fp1);
    ch = fgetc(fp1);
    printf("c=%c\n", ch); */
    fclose(fp1);
}
```

Comment: Please share your source, and tell us what went wrong... did you see any errors?

Comment: http://www.includehelp.com/c-programs/capitalize-first-character-of-each-word-in-string.aspx

Comment: I am pretty sure that your course materials contains all info necessary to solve this. Have you tried going back to them?

Comment: @VenkatRao  You noticed that example gives a memory fault when you enter 101 characters?

Comment: that is because the length of character array is given to be 100 in the example @GerardH.Pille

Comment: @VenkatRao No, it's because they forget to check their input.  Very bad example.

Comment: There is no error but it can't produce proper output that i am looking for.

Comment: `if (ch = = ' '|| ch == '\n')`? Can you submit code that actually compiles please?

Comment: please ckeck it I give the actual code that i compiled.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine

Comment: You are opening the file "a+", meaning reading and appending. I don't think that allows you to write, modify the file, as you do with the fseek and fputc.

Comment: "I give the actual code that i compiled".  No, you did not.

Comment: Just replace  "a+" by "r+" and your program works.

Comment: If every write to the file appends to the file, you'll never get the 'right' result.  Therefore, the `a` in `"a+"` is completely wrong.  You need `"r+"` to avoid clobbering the data in the file, but that allows you to alter it.  Your algorithm isn't going to spot the `h` in `how are you`.  You need to think your word boundaries more carefully.  What should happen with "`it won't work`"?

Comment: when calling `fopen()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  when calling `fseek()`, always check (!=-1) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `if(ch>=97 && ch<=122)`  None of us want to search an ASCII table to determine which characters those number represent.  Suggest using `'a'` and `'z'`.   However, in the header file `ctype.h`  are the functions/macros `toupper()` and `isalpha()`  which will greatly simplify your code.

Comment: regarding: `if(ch==' ' || ch=='\n')`  this overlooks the <tab> char (\t)  Suggest using `isspace()` from the header file `ctype.h`

Comment: regarding: `char ch;`  the returned type from `fgetc()` is an `int`, so the declaration should be: `int ch;`

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <ctype.h>`  for functions like: `toupper()`

Comment: the return type from `main()` is always `int`, regardless of what visual studio will allow you to get away with

Comment: the posted code, even after the suggest corrections, does not properly handle `//ch=fgetc(fp1)`  nor any other instances where some word is immediately preceded by anything other than 'white space'

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the file in place is a bad idea. Using standard streams for this is cumbersome and inefficient.

Here is a simple filter that reads `stdin` and writes the modified words to `stdout`:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c, lastc = '\n';

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (!isalpha(lastc))
            c = toupper(c);
        putchar(c);
        lastc = c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that the above code works for ASCII text files. It may not work for non ASCII files, especially if they are encoded with a multi-byte encoding such as UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that also comes up when converting to title case is, "What are the acceptable preceding characters to trigger capitalization of the first character in a word?" Sometimes, as in your example, you may want `Morning.How` with `how` considered a separate word and capitalized. Other times, you may only want to consider words following a whitespace.

You can tailor this by specifying a list of ending characters (`ends` below) that will be followed by a first character converted to caps. You can either set a macro defining a string constant, pass a second short string to your titlecase function, or just specify the `ends` list in your function itself.

Generally, I wouldn't capitalize within a string made up by dot separators, but there is nothing wrong with it. That is where having the flexibility of an `ends` list pays dividends. You simply tailor the string to fit your needs. An example would be:

```
/** convert string to title case based on 'ends'.
 *  returns pointer to 'str' with words converted to 
 *  initial uppercase if the word follows one of the 
 *  characters specified in 'ends'.
 */
char *str2title (char *str)
{
    if (!str) return NULL;    /* handle NULL and empty-string */
    if (!*str) return str;

    char *p = str,            /* pointer to string */
        *ends = " \t\n.",     /* set of acceptable ends */
        last = ' ';           /* previous character seen */

    for (; *p; p++) {                     /* loop over string */
        for (char *e = ends; *e; e++)     /* loop over ends */
            /* if last is end and current is lowercase */
            if (last == *e && ('a' <= *p && *p <= 'z'))
                *p += 'A' - 'a';          /* convert to upper */
        last = *p;
    }

    return str;
}
```

There are many ways to approach this problem. Learn from them all.

Answer (score -1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. uses the OPs algorithm, warts and all
3. properly checks for and handles any errors
4. uses appropriate horizontal spacing: inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators for ease of readability and understanding
5. documents why each header file is included
6. comments the status at key points in the code
7. incorporates the comments to the OPs question
8. uses the facilities found in header file `ctype.h` to avoid crypic numbers, etc
9. consistently indents the code, using 4 spaces for each indent level

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>    // fopen(), perror(), fgetc(), fclose(),
                      // fseek(), fputc(),
                      // FILE, EOF
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>    // toupper(), isspace(), isalpha()


int main( void )
{
    int ch;

    FILE *fp1 = fopen( "asiftext.txt", "r+" );
    if( !fp1 )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    while( ( ch = fgetc( fp1 ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if( !isspace( ch ) )
        {
            continue;
        }

        // when here, 'ch' is a 'white space' char
        if( ( ch = fgetc( fp1 ) ) == EOF )
        {
            break;
        }

        // when here, 'ch' is possibly the
        // first letter of a word
        if( isalpha( ch ) )
        {  // then 'ch' is alphabetic
            // adjust file pointer
            if( fseek( fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR ) )
            {
                perror( "fseek failed" );
                fclose( fp1 );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            // implied else, fseek successful

            // overwrite with uppercase char
            fputc( toupper( ch ), fp1 );
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);
}
```

The following proposed code implements a (two state) state machine and addresses the shortcomings of the OPs algorithm.

```
#include <stdio.h>    // fopen(), perror(), fgetc(), fclose(),
                      // fseek(), fputc(),
                      // FILE, EOF
#include <stdlib.h>   // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#include <ctype.h>    // toupper(), isspace(), isalpha()

enum state { notInWord, InWord };

int main( void )
{
    enum state currentState = notInWord;

    int ch;

    FILE *fp1 = fopen( "asiftext.txt", "r+" );
    if( !fp1 )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful


    while(  (ch = fgetc( fp1 ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if( notInWord == currentState )
        {
            if( isalpha( ch ) )
            {
                currentState = InWord;

                // adjust file pointer
                if( fseek( fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR ) )
                {
                    perror( "fseek failed" );
                    fclose( fp1 );
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                // implied else, fseek successful

                // overwrite with uppercase char
                fputc( toupper( ch ), fp1 );
            }

            else // not alpha
            {
                currentState = notInWord;
            }
        }

        else  // currentState = InWord
        {
            if( !isalpha( ch ) )
            {
                currentState = notInWord;
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(fp1);
}
```

here is the output from the corrected code when run against a copy of the corrected source code:

```
#Include <Stdio.H>    // Fopen(), Perror(), Fgetc(), Fclose(),
                      // Fseek(), Fputc(),
                      // FILE, EOF
#Include <Stdlib.H>   // Exit(), EXIT_FAILURE
#Include <Ctype.H>    // Toupper(), Isspace(), Isalpha()

Enum State { NotInWord, InWord };

Int Main( Void )
{
    Enum State CurrentState = NotInWord;

    Int Ch;

    FILE *Fp1 = Fopen( "Asiftext.Txt", "R+" );
    If( !Fp1 )
    {
        Perror( "Fopen Failed" );
        Exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // Implied Else, Fopen Successful


    While(  (Ch = Fgetc( Fp1 ) ) != EOF )
    {
        If( NotInWord == CurrentState )
        {
            If( Isalpha( Ch ) )
            {
                CurrentState = InWord;

                // Adjust File Pointer
                If( Fseek( Fp1, -1, SEEK_CUR ) )
                {
                    Perror( "Fseek Failed" );
                    Fclose( Fp1 );
                    Exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }

                // Implied Else, Fseek Successful

                // Overwrite With Uppercase Char
                Fputc( Toupper( Ch ), Fp1 );
            }

            Else // Not Alpha
            {
                CurrentState = NotInWord;
            }
        }

        Else  // CurrentState = InWord
        {
            If( !Isalpha( Ch ) )
            {
                CurrentState = NotInWord;
            }
        }
    }

    Fclose(Fp1);
}
```

Comment: surely this doesnt capitalize the first letter of the file

Comment: @pm100,  True enough.  A simple state machine that is initialized to 'not in word' and when it sees the first char changes state to 'in word', and back at the input of any not alpha character would be a much better algorithm.  However, I tried to stay with the algorithm used by the OP.

Comment: so it doesnt do #2 in your list then,

Comment: @pm100 Very alert. Chapeau!

Comment: This code has undefined behavior because you do not call `fseek()` for each change between reading from and writing to the file.  Furthermore, `main()` should return `0` for better portability (implicit `return 0` was introduced in C99 only). Finally, the initial of each word should be uppercased, including words that do not follow a space, as per the OP's example: `good morning.how are you?`. no space between `morning` and `how`.

Comment: I have added a version of the code that addresses the shortcomings of my first posted code and the shortcomings of the OPs algorithm

Comment: I have added the result of running my 'corrected' code against a copy of that code.

Comment: @chqrlie,  Notice there is no/zero/nada necessity to use a call to `fseek()` other than when the code is going to change some char in the input file.
  If the user wants to use some obsolete C compiler, (like visual studio) then they can 'tweak' the code so it runs on that obsolete compiler with no warnings, etc.  I see no reason for me to write the code to support any/every C compiler ever written.

Comment: @user3629249: I did not say you had to use `fseek()` for each byte read from the file, but you need an extra `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_CUR);` after the `fputc()` because you switch back from writing to reading. It is still a requirement as of C11 for proper operation, even if some current C libraries seem to work correctly without it.